# What is wrong with this while loop, it seems not ending as the print statement ager it is not executed

Tags: python

I am an absolute beginner in programming (just started yesterday and my major is not CS). I have been struggling with this while loop as I don't know why this print statement is not executed(sometimes it prints as "1"). Please tell me where is wrong. Thanks, guys.

```
current_saving = 0
# This program intends to calculate the how many months the down
# portion can be paid
annual_input = int(input("Enter your annual salary:"))
portion_saved = float(
    input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:"))
total_cost = int(input("Enter the cost of your dream home:"))
portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
months = 0
while current_saving <= portion_down_payment:
    current_saving = annual_input / 12 * portion_saved + current_saving * 0.04 / 12
    months = months + 1
print(months)
```

Comment: As long as the condition after "while" is fulfilled the loop is executed on and on. The "print" only happens when/if loop is left (condition is wrong).

Comment: Are you using an IDE? This won't even run, since `#` is what starts comments in Python, not `/*`. An IDE is helpful for catching things like that.

Comment: It looks like you meant: current_saving += ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is an **interactive** community. Interact with the community so they can tell if your question has been answered. If an answer meets your needs accept the answer. If your question has not been answered add comments. Possibly clarify your question. The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) provides information to help you succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code to accumulate savings.

```
current_saving = 0
# This program intends to calculate the how many months the down
# portion can be paid
annual_input = int(input("Enter your annual salary:"))
portion_saved = float(
    input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:"))
total_cost = int(input("Enter the cost of your dream home:"))
portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
months = 0
while current_saving <= portion_down_payment:
    # Accumulate savings
    current_saving = current_saving + annual_input / 12 * portion_saved + \
                                    current_saving * 0.04 / 12
    print(f'{current_saving=}') # Comment out this line to not print the accumulation
    months = months + 1
print(months)
```

Test Reults

```
Enter your annual salary:5000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:.5
Enter the cost of your dream home:10000
current_saving=208.33333333333334
current_saving=417.36111111111114
current_saving=627.0856481481482
current_saving=837.5092669753087
current_saving=1048.6342978652262
current_saving=1260.4630788581103
current_saving=1472.9979557876372
current_saving=1686.2412823069292
current_saving=1900.195419914619
current_saving=2114.862737981001
current_saving=2330.245613774271
current_saving=2546.3464324868523
12
```

Comment: I see my answer has neither been accepted as the correct answer nor responded to in any way. I am not offended. I will continue to monitor for any interaction from the individual who originally posted the question or others,

Comment: Thank you. I have found my problem that  I didn't add `current_saving` in the while loop. That's why the loop never ends. I have accepted this answer.